Is it possible to manipulate heat kernel on H-type groups?
In Nathaniel Eldredge's work see here, he uses the explicit expression of the Heat Kernel on H-type groups (for example the Heisenberg group is an H-type group):
$$p_t(x,z)=  (2\pi )^{-m} (4 \pi )^{-n} \int_{R^m} e^{i \langle \lambda , z \rangle -\frac{1}{4}|\lambda|\, cotgh (t|\lambda|)\,|x|^2  }\Big( \frac{|\lambda|}{\sinh( t |\lambda|)}\Big)^n d\lambda$$
to establish the known Gaussian lower and upper bounds for the heat kernel, i.e.$$
C_1 Q_te^{-\frac{d(x,z)^2}{4t}} \leq p_t(x,z) \leq C_2Q_te^{-\frac{d(x,z)^2}{4t}},
$$
Consider $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ the semigroup generated by the sublaplacian, in the Heisenberg group for example. It is known that $T(t)f = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d+1}} p_t(x,y)f(y)dy$ My question is, if faced with such a difficult expression to $p_t$, it is possible to manipulate it to obtain the semigroup property
$$T(t)T(s)f = T(t+s)f$$
from the convolution of $f$ with $p_t$, in the same way as is done for the semigroup generated by the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^d$? More specifically, is there a way to join the kernels $p_t(x,z)p_s(z,w) \approx p_{t+s}(x,w)$?
